# How to read Javascript documentation?

Tags: javascript, documentation, indexeddb

I am trying to learn the fine points of IndexedDB and going through [documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/).  Being a Javascript noob, I am having trouble understanding some of the documentation.

So through tinkering, i figured out that code to handle deleteDatabase call is this:

```
var req = indexedDB.deleteDatabase(DB_NAME);
req.onsuccess = function () {
    console.log("Deleted database successfully");
};
req.onerror = function (e) {                        
    console.log(e.message);
};
req.onblocked = function () {                        
    console.log('Database is blocked right now...try again later');
};
```

Where in the documentation (or even intellisense in tools like VS or Sublime, browser dev tools and the like) does it state that the `.onerror` event passes the error object `e`, but the `.onblocked` does not.

Comment: Can you please edit your question title to be more specific to indexedDB?

Comment: @Josh I brought up IndexedDB as an example. But I regularly run into similar issues with other features as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we'll look at the definition of `req`'s type,  `IDBOpenRequest`.

http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#idl-def-IDBOpenDBRequest

This interface declares `onblocked` as:

```
attribute EventHandler onblocked;
```

The interface extends `IDBRequest`.

http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#idl-def-IDBRequest

This interface declares the `onerror` attribute as:

```
attribute EventHandler onerror;
```

Now we'll check what `EventHandler` is.

http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#dependencies

> The terms and algorithms document base URL, event handler attributes, event handler event type, Function, origin, same origin, structured clone, structured clone algorithm, task, task source, and queue a task are defined by the HTML 5 specification [HTML5].

The Indexed Database API specification doesn't define it. It uses the definition from the HTML 5 specification.

http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#references

They link to the full specification of HTML5.

We navigate to the part that defines `EventHandler`.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#eventhandler

```
[TreatNonCallableAsNull]
callback EventHandlerNonNull = any (Event event);
typedef EventHandlerNonNull? EventHandler;
```

So when `EventHandler` is not `null`, it's a function that takes an `Event` argument.

Comment: and then right under that, "For historical reasons, the `onerror` handler has different arguments:" ugh

Comment: So if I understand you correctly...other than the footnote stating that oneerror is handled differently for historical reasons... there is no way to infer that onblocked has no parameters but onerror does???

Comment: I wouldn't even think that the footnote applies to IndexedDB. Besides, according to `OnErrorEventHandlerNonNull`, the first argument should be `Event` or `DOMString`, neither of which has a `message` attribute. `onblocked` should have a parameter, the simple `Event` of type `blocked`.

Comment: I am further now confused.  Are you saying that the documentation is incorrect?  Or incomplete?  In other words, just going by documentation alone (and no online samples), would I be able to construct the code in the question?

Comment: It's a specification. It's hard to say that a specification is wrong. If browsers don't comply with it, then that's different. I know I wouldn't be able to come up with `req.onerror = function (e) { console.log(e.message); }'` given these specs.

Answer (score 0):

You can get pretty far just reading the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API).